# Creating templates for turning on and off multiple layers at once in the ToC

Tags: arcgis-pro

Is there a way to create a template for which layers should be visible in the map? I work with a database which has 50+ layers, all of which I need as I jump from task to task, but I rarely need more than 5-10 active at a time. Right now I usually have between 30-40 active and it grinds my CPU to a halt. Manually turning them on and off is possible but is a hassle compared to some sort of stored setting.

Comment: Have you tried using the Ctrl key?

Comment: You may group layer and turn on and off the group (useful if you have some thematic or use case grouping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded by @PolyGeo holding the Crtl Key down when you tick/untick the visibility checkbox will turn all layers on/off. First you need to select all layers in the contents pane, use the Shift key for that. See video below.

[image: Video]

Comment: There’s usually/often no need to select all layers. Simply Ctrl clicking any checkbox toggles all layers at the same level to the opposite visibility.